# chartjs-node-canvas install (build) error

Tags: node.js, chart.js

I want to render a chart to use with my discord bot and so far all the tutorials i have seen are using the chartjs-node-canvas module. But it gives errors when installing.
If someone gives me an alternative package to chartjs-node-canvas this is perfectly fine but i would prefer just solving this error and using the existing package.

Since stackoverflow does not allow adding text files (and if i just paste the text it is more than 30000 characters) here is a link to a pastebin with the npm log
pastebin.com/raw/yXrTyq85

Comment: You should post the  minimal, reproducibe code as plain text here instead of a link

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem lies in the installation of node-canvas which is a dependency for chartjs-node-canvas. After spending a lot of time researching why the library isn't getting installed, I got a lead to the following link: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki#installation-guides

I installed the below-mentioned dependencies on my machine and used a node version of 16.x
This did the work for me.
Here is how I installed the required dependencies:

```
brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg
```

After installing these dependencies, you can install the library using npm or yarn.